# Expected value (mean) is zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

I have that $y_i=Kx_i + e$ with $e \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2}I)$.

Also $$p(x_i)=\mathcal{N}(0,I).$$

I saw this: $\mathbf{E}[y_i \mid K] = \mathbf{E}[Kx_i + e] = K\mathbf{E}[x_i] + \mathbf{E}[e]= 0.$

I don't see how is this equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write something like
$$Q \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_Q, \sigma_Q^{2}I),$$

then you are saying that

$$\mathbb{E}[Q] = \mu_Q.$$

Comment: oh my... thanks i guess

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to upvote the answer!

Comment: It wont allow me to do so